# Resources mentioned in preload link headers are not pre-loading

Tags: http, preload, web-performance

I'm trying to flatten some waterfalls for a web service. Currently, I'm seeing this ugly pattern:

```
document: WWWWWWWWDDDDD
resource:              WWWWWWWWWDDDDD
resource:              WWWWWWWWWDDDDD

W = Waiting (TTFB)
D = Content Download
```

To flatten this somewhat, I'm trying to get the sub-resources downloading sooner. To do this, I'm using the `Link` header and stuffing it with preload directives. Also, I'm flushing the headers before sending content. As I understood it, this should allow the preloads to be discovered in the first received chunk of bytes before waiting for the entire document to be downloaded. Sample `Link` header:

```
link: <https://some.domain.com/foo.min.js>; rel=preload; as=script; crossorigin,<//some.other.com/script.js>; rel=preload; as=script; crossorigin
```

I'm pretty sure the browser is *seeing* these links, because it complained before I had all those attributes correct, like `crossorigin`. However, the waterfall remains as before; none of the sub-resources that are set to be preloaded are downloaded until the entire document is downloaded. I'd expect something more like this:

```
document: WWWWWWWWDDDDD
resource:         WWWWWWWWWDDDDD
resource:         WWWWWWWWWDDDDD
```

What is causing the link header to be ignored by Chrome?

Comment: You shouldn’t need `crossorigin` on script requests (unless they are loaded via JavaScript XHR instead of via a `<script>` tag?). What error were you seeing before adding that attribute?

Comment: @BarryPollard, I could try removing those. My links also contain some fonts that require crossorigin, so I universally added `crossorigin` to everything. Think that would be blocking preloads?

Comment: Yeah because it will preload it as a cross origin and then have to re-request as non-cross origin resource. Though would have thought it would have show twice in Network tab in that case...